# Echo equivalent in PowerShell for script testing

Tags: powershell

I would like to output variables and values out in a [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) script by setting up flags and seeing the data matriculate throughout the script.

How would I do this?

For example, what would be the PowerShell equivalent to the following PHP code?

```
echo "filesizecounter: " . $filesizecounter
```

Comment: Check out the script-editor/debugger that comes with [PowerGUI](http://www.powergui.org/index.jspa). It may be suitable for what you are doing. I understand that Powershell 2 comes with a debugger too (but I haven't tried it).

Answer (score 380, accepted):

There are several ways:

[`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host): Write directly to the console, not included in function/cmdlet output. Allows foreground and background colour to be set.

[`Write-Debug`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-debug): Write directly to the console, if [`$DebugPreference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables#debugpreference) set to Continue or Stop.

[`Write-Verbose`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-verbose): Write directly to the console, if [`$VerbosePreference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables#verbosepreference) set to Continue or Stop.

The latter is intended for extra optional information, `Write-Debug` for debugging (so would seem to fit in this case).

**Additional**: In PSH2 (at least) scripts using cmdlet binding will automatically get the `-Verbose` and `-Debug` switch parameters, locally enabling `Write-Verbose` and `Write-Debug` (i.e. overriding the preference variables) as compiled cmdlets and providers do.

Comment: The nice thing about Write-Debug and Write-Verbose is that you can leave your debug statements in your code, and just turn on the output when you need it using the appropriate preference variable.  Saves time and is a nice feature for other users of  your functions.

Comment: You also want to get familiar with Out-String, because with any non-trivial object, you'll need to use that to convert the object to a display-able string before using any of those three Write-* cmdlets.

Answer (score 172):

Powershell has an alias mapping `echo` to `Write-Output`, so you can use:

```
echo "filesizecounter : $filesizecounter"
```

Comment: `echo` is an alias to `Write-Output` as per Microsoft's [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849921.aspx) and discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17623902/857209)

Comment: Thanks Glenn, it looks like the alias has been remapped in the 6 years since I posted this. Which is good, one really shouldn't use Write-Host as it bypasses the pipeline. I've updated my reply to indicate this. Thanks!

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to bypass the pipeline if all you want to do is echo "debug" output to the console to trace execution of a script? Write-Output has a weird side-effect where the content of the last call to Write-Output will be left on the stack, overriding any variable you attempt to explicitly return from a function. Side-effects like that feel like an awfully screwy way for a language to behave.

Answer (score 44):

PowerShell interpolates, does it not?

In PHP

```
echo "filesizecounter: " . $filesizecounter
```

can also be written as:

```
echo "filesizecounter: $filesizecounter"
```

In PowerShell something like this should suit your needs:

```
Write-Host "filesizecounter: $filesizecounter"
```

Answer (score 31):

```
Write-Host "filesizecounter : " $filesizecounter
```

Answer (score 14):

By far the easiest way to echo in powershell, is just create the string object and let the pipeline output it:

```
$filesizecounter = 8096
"filesizecounter : $filesizecounter"
```

Of course, you do give up some flexibility when not using the Write-* methods.

Answer (score 12):

echo is alias to [Write-Output](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849921.aspx) although it looks the same as [Write-Host](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849877.aspx).

It isn't *[What is the difference between echo and Write-Host in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17623644)*.

echo is an alias for Write-Output, which writes to the Success output stream. This allows output to be processed through pipelines or redirected into files. Write-Host writes directly to the console, so the output can't be redirected/processed any further.

Answer (score 10):

The Write-host work fine.

```
$Filesize = (Get-Item $filepath).length;
Write-Host "FileSize= $filesize";
```

Answer (score 9):

It should also be mentioned, that [Set-PSDebug](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-psdebug?view=powershell-7) is similar to the old-school `echo on` batch command:

```bsh
Set-PSDebug -Trace 1
```

This command will result in showing every line of the executing script:

> When the `Trace` parameter has a value of `1`, each line of script is traced as it runs. When the parameter has a value of `2`, variable assignments, function calls, and script calls are also traced. If the `Step` parameter is specified, you're prompted before each line of the script runs.

Comment: I think this is the right answer, frankly as the default behavior of PS is not to write out commands automatically. +1 Vote!

Answer (score 7):

PowerShell has aliases for several common commands like `echo`. Type the following in PowerShell:

```
Get-Alias echo
```

to get a response:

```
CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Alias           echo -> Write-Output
```

Even Get-Alias has an alias `gal -> Get-Alias`. You could write `gal echo` to get the alias for `echo`.

```
gal echo
```

Other aliases are listed here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/using-familiar-command-names?view=powershell-6

`cat dir mount rm cd echo move rmdir chdir erase popd sleep clear h ps sort cls history pushd tee copy kill pwd type del lp r write diff ls ren`

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if it's wise to do so, but you can just write

```
"filesizecounter: " + $filesizecounter
```

And it should output:

> filesizecounter: value

Comment: `"filesizecounter:  $filesizecounter"` is even shorter.

Answer (score 2):

Try `Get-Content .\yourScript.PS1` and you will see the content of your script.

also you can insert this line in your scrip code:

```
get-content .\scriptname.PS1
script code
script code
```

....

Comment: Doesn't show actual values processed (e.g. env var substitution) so not an answer to the question asked.