# How to write to the console in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I am having a little confusion about the various ways to print (echo) to the console. I have seen that there are multiple ways to write output to the console, such as:

```
Write-Host "Hello world1"
"Hello World2"
Out-Host -InputObject "Hello World3"
```

All three ways will print to the console. The middle one is somehow simpler and less verbose and easier to use. I also find that when you write a function such as:

```
function GetValues()
{
    "1"
    "2"
}
```

It still returns two strings in the pipeline:

And I'm still able to print out the values:

```
foreach ($s in GetValues)
{
    Write-Host "s: " $s
}
```

The thing that I have found was that using just the quoted string doesn't always appear on custom hosts, and that I have had to use [Write-Host](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849877.aspx) to get values to print on custom hosts.

Somehow I find this confusing. Is `"Print something"` supposed to be an alias to `Write-Host` or what is the intent?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Echo equivalent in PowerShell for script testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707646/echo-equivalent-in-powershell-for-script-testing)

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Default behaviour of PowerShell is just to dump everything that falls out of a pipeline without being picked up by another pipeline element or being assigned to a variable (or redirected) into `Out-Host`. What `Out-Host` does is obviously host-dependent.

Just letting things fall out of the pipeline is *not* a substitute for `Write-Host` which exists for the sole reason of outputting text in the host application.

If you want output, then use the `Write-*` cmdlets. If you want return values from a function, then just dump the objects there without any cmdlet.

Answer (score 73):

The middle one writes to the pipeline. `Write-Host` and `Out-Host` writes to the console. 'echo' is an alias for `Write-Output` which writes to the pipeline as well. The best way to write to the console would be using the `Write-Host` cmdlet.

When an object is written to the pipeline it can be consumed by other commands in the chain. For example:

```
"hello world" | Do-Something
```

but this won't work since `Write-Host` writes to the console, not to the pipeline (Do-Something will not get the string):

```
Write-Host "hello world" | Do-Something
```

Comment: This answer is technically correct, but I suspect it leads a neophyte PowerShell user astray.  The first rule of effective PowerShell is to produce output that is useful in the pipeline.  If you are using Write-Host very much, you are probably doing it wrong.

Comment: Well, isn't that what the OP asked, how to write to the console? There's a difference between writing to the host and writing to the pipeline, and one has to know what each do. I'll update my answer with a clarification.

Comment: The real kicker is trying to write to console a string of code. That is, apparently, impossible to do easily. Try it: Echo "Get-ADUser -Filter "UserPrincipalName -like 'randomkeywords*'" -Properties *"