# Powershell 'mystring' vs Write-Host 'mystring'

Tags: powershell

Having a string on its own in Powershell outputs it to the console. At first glance it looks like i behaves as Write-Host. Does it?

```
function AnyFunction(){
    'aaa'
    Write-Host 'bbb'
}
```

Comment: `'aaa'` is the same as `write-output 'aaa'`.  Avoid `write-host` / use instead `write-output` or `write-information`; the latter outputs depending on the `$informationPreference` property.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10832000/best-way-to-write-to-the-console-in-powershell) out!

Comment: Worth noting that `Write-Information` was introduced with PowerShell v5 and is not available in earlier versions. `Write-Host` writes output directly to the host console (thus bypassing pipelines, etc.) and should *only* be used for displaying information to a user.