# How can I write a message to the console with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I have tried this:

```
# Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
$VerbosePreference = 'Continue'
Write-Verbose "ABC"
$DebugPreference = "Continue"
Write-Debug "Something went wrong."
```

But both messages come either with the word: VERBOSE or DEBUG before the actual message.

Is there a way I can just display the message content only?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Echo equivalent in PowerShell for script testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/707646/echo-equivalent-in-powershell-for-script-testing)

Comment: You can just output a string:

    "ABC"

Or, if you insist that a cmdlet would be used, use `Write-Host` or `Write-Default`. See linked question for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Write-Host` is what you would use to write a message to the host.  Note that in V4 and below, you can't capture this sort of output to a log file.  Starting with V5, you can capture host messages because Write-Host has been updated to use the new Information stream. Likewise in V5, you could just use `Write-Information` directly.